# How to check if a pair of coordinates is within a range in Numpy?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, coordinates

I have an array of coordinates:

```py
>> b
array([[11,  1],
       [45, 10],
       [-4,  5],
       [ 8,  9]])
```

And I want to check whether each x value is between 4 and 15 and each y value is between 1 and 7. If a pair of coordinates qualifies, then a `True` should be added to the list, else `False`. And this should give me

```py
array([True, False, False, False])
```

I am aware I can do this using list comprehension, but is there a faster/neater way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((b >= [4, 1]) & (b <= [15, 7])).all(axis=1)

Out: array([ True, False, False, False])
```